# how to retrieve jwt stored in cookies

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, jwt, mern

I am exercising authentication for MERN stack and I decided to store JWT inside cookies, where during login new token will be sent to the cookies and during logout the function checks for the token from the request and clears the cookie and removes the token from database. I can send the cookie inside node with `res.cookie` on http://localhost:3000/ without errors and see the content from chrome application, but when I console.log the cookie with `req.cookies` from http://localhost:3000/main, it is undefined

**backend**

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const dbConnect = require("./dbConnect");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const refreshTokenRoutes = require("./routes/refreshToken");

const port = process.env.PORT;

dbConnect(); //connect to mongoDb database

app.use(
  cors({
    // origin: "http://localhost:3000/main",
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000/main"],
    methods: "GET, POST, UPDATE, DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/api", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/refreshToken", refreshTokenRoutes);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**auth.js**

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //check if the input is in a valid format
    const { error } = logInBodyValidation(req.body);
    if (error) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: error.details[0].message });
    }

    //check if the user is registered in the database
    const user = await users.findOne({
      email: req.body.email,
    });
    const passwordCheck = await bcrypt.compare(
      req.body.password,
      user.password
    );

    if (!user || !passwordCheck) {
      res
        .status(401)
        .json({ error: true, message: "invalid email or password" });
    }

    const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await generateToken(user);

    res
      .cookie("jwtoken", refreshToken, {
        maxAge: 1296000000,
        path: "/",
        domain: "localhost:3000",
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json({
        error: false,
        accessToken,
        refreshToken,
        message: "Logged in sucessfully!",
      });
  } catch (error) {
    // res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});
```

`req.cookies` returns the cookies

**refreshToken.js**

```
// logout
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { error } = refreshTokenBodyValidation(req.user);
    if (error)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ error: true, message: error.details[0].message });
    const userToken = await UserToken.findOne({
      token: req.user.refreshToken,
    });
    if (!userToken)
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ error: false, message: "Logged Out Sucessfully!" });
    await userToken.remove();
    res
      .clearCookie("jwtoken")
      .status(200)
      .json({ error: false, message: "Logged Out Sucessfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});
```

`req.cookies` returns `[Object: null prototype] {}`

**Frontend**

**Login.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Login = ({ email, password, setEmail, setPassword }) => {
  const loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
        }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      localStorage.setItem("token", data);
      console.log(data);
      // window.location.href = "/main";
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={loginUser}>
        <input
          title="Email"
          // value={email}
          placeholder="Enter E-mail"
          type="email"
          className="email"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setEmail(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input
          title="Password"
          // value={password}
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          type="password"
          className="pass"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setPassword(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button>Log in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Logout.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Logout = () => {
  const logoutUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/refeshToken/", {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      method: "GET",
    });
    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.user) {
      alert("Logged out successfuly");
      window.location.href = "/";
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="logout">
      <button
        className="logout_button"
        title="Logout"
        onClick={(e) => logoutUser(e)}
      >
        Log out
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Logout;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was a CORS error, must include `credentials: "include"` in the logout fetch request header